# How is it possible to Upgrade network radio chip to 802.11ac on My Toshiba Laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, toshiba-laptop

The Toshiba model is:  C55T-A5103

The output of this command shows current network capabilities built-in:

```
netsh wlan show drivers

Interface name: Wi-Fi  

    Driver                    : Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E   

NIC  

    Vendor                    : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  
    Provider                  : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  
    Date                      : 9/1/2015  
    Version                   : 2023.17.731.2015  
    INF file                  : C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem45.inf  
    Files                     : 2 total  
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\rtwlane.sys  
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\Rtlihvs.dll  
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver  
    Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b  
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes  
    802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes  
<...>
```

Ideally it would be a quick solder job with a matching pin-out piece (radio hardware chip) followed by installing a standardized driver.  It would be great to have the new parts, such as available in a USB dongle installed within the case on the motherboard.

Comment: Or you could just pull it out of its slot and install the new card.....in the same slot.

Comment: I haven't dissected this laptop very deeply: does the motherboard have slots like in a desktop?  That would make it easy

Comment: "Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E" yes you have a pci-e slot.

Comment: Yes most laptops have slots for Ram and Wireless cards. I have never seen one with a wifi card soldered to the mobo, but i'm sure they exist.

Comment: That helps a lot: now I know to look.  Is there a standard name for the physical form that this type card hast (the name tied to the pin-out or type of connector for instance)?